# PHP array performance - memory wise

Tags: php

I have an array of size 5 MB, I am passing it to functions to functions (I am not passing it **by reference**)

```
foo( $arr );

function foo( $arr ) {
    ....
    bar( $arr );
    ....
}

function bar( $arr ) {
    ....
    test( $arr );
    ....
}

function test( $arr ) {
    ....
    test2( $arr );
    ....
}
```

PHP passes array values **by value** (copy of value) by default to functions.

my question is,  if this array value is passed to 100 functions calls, will the PHP consumes **100 x 5 MB = 500 MB** of memory ?

How the PHP handles big arrays ( in memory wise ) on function calls?

Comment: Couldn't tell ya, but you might want to look into iterators and foreach loops, you can probably have a lot better memory consumption that way.

Comment: You can find out with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a code to test:

```
<?php

    function testnochanges($arr1){
        foreach($arr1 as $val){
            //
        }
        return $arr1;
    }

    function testwithchanges($arr1){
        $arr1[] = 1;
        return $arr1;
    }

    echo "Stage 0: Mem usage is: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br />";

      for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
        $arr[] = rand();
      }

     echo "Stage 1 (Array Created): Mem usage is: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br />";


     $arrtest1 = testnochanges($arr);
     echo "Stage 2 (Function did NO changes to array): Mem usage is: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br />";

     $arrtest2 = testwithchanges($arr);
     echo "Stage 3 (Function DID changes to array): Mem usage is: " . memory_get_usage() . "<br />";


    ?>
```

and here is a output after i run it:

```
Stage 0: Mem usage is: 330656
Stage 1 (Array Created): Mem usage is: 8855296
Stage 2 (Function did NO changes to array): Mem usage is: 8855352
Stage 3 (Function DID changes to array): Mem usage is: 14179864
```

On **stage 0** we can see that before array is created PHP is already using some space in memory. After creating first array (**Stage 1**) we can see a big change in memory usage as expected. But after calling function `testnochanges` function and creating `$arrtest1` on **Stage 2**, we see that memory usage did not change a lot. It's because  we did no changes to `$arr`, so `$arrtest1` and `$arr` still are pointing to the same array. But on **Stage 3**, where we call `testwithchanges` function, and add an element to `$arr` PHP performs `copy-on-write` and returned array which is assigned to `$arrtest2` now uses different part of memory and again we see a big grow of memory usage.

*Dry conclusion*: If you copy array to another array and do not change it, memory usage stays the same as both arrays are pointed to the same one. If you change the array PHP performs `copy-on-write` and, of course memory usage grows.

Good thing to read: [Be wary of garbage collection, part 2](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/18/1/11).

Comment: Further to this OP, http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html is an explanation of what's going on behind the scenes, if you're interested.

Comment: Interesting ... memory will be allocated only when we change it, good point to learn. Thanks !.

Comment: @SuVeRa I have edited answer with new code and new test to ensure how it exactly works with functions.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to really find out how your particular use case performs is to complete a benchmark (quick and dirty is fine).  If you are having trouble with performance, you may want to look into SPL.  For example, `SplFixedArray` can save memory when dealing larger arrays, granted you know the size beforehand.  Also, newer versions of PHP handle garbage collection much better than previous versions, so upgrading may also help.

If you decide to run benchmarks, this will get you started (compares SPL with raw arrays):
https://github.com/elazar/spl-benchmarks